# Ngb Date Picker minDate and maxDate not working as expected

Tags: angular, ngb-datepicker

I have used ngbDatePicker for selecting multiple dates.

I want to disable date before the current date.

But when I use `minDate` directive only the past month  was disabled not the dates before to-day.

Template:

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp   [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t">
</ngb-datepicker>

<ng-template #t let-date="date" let-focused="focused">
  <span class="custom-day" (click)="onDateSelection($event,date)"
        [class.focused]="focused"
        [class.range]="isFrom(date) || isTo(date) || isInside(date) || isHovered(date)"
        [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
        [class.selected]="isDateSelected(date)"
        (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
        (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
    {{ date.day }}
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

I have [stack-blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o19x1h?file=src/app/multi-date-picker/multi-date-picker.html%3E) example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to delete that custom date template, you need to handle `disabled` attribute in the template.

Here's [updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mn5aap) with the **dayTemplate**

Comment: .this works fine is there any way to change. that unavailable data color in date picker

Comment: Yes. You can change the styles to whatever you want. For example, i've replaced class for disabled elements to my own by doing ```[class.day-disabled]="disabled"``` and added corresponding changes to ```styles``` definitions in the component. Check out the stackblitz above - I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `[dayTemplate]="t"`

Try like this:

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp   [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" [displayMonths]="2" >
</ngb-datepicker>
```

See [Updated working Stackbiltz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfckw3)

Comment: if I remove that. I cant select multiple dates any more